# Action Toolbars in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

There is a TactionToolabr in my form , i want to add some actions to it so i dragged and dropped some actions(which i have already used in my action main menu)from action Manager.

Everything worked fine until i

> 1. double clicked on the action in my Action toolbar
> 2. put some code to it
> 3. returned to form designer,

the action which i double clicked disappeared.

I want to use the actions in my main menu to be available in action toolbar. What can i do.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an issue with the designer.

You can add your code before you drag & drop your action on the toolbar, or you can add your event with selecting the action on the toolbar (simple click) and double-click on the event `OnExecute` from the Objects Inspector.

Comment: Is that all versions of Delphi having this bug

Comment: I don't know.. I reproduce it on my XE2

Comment: Have you updated it to update 1 or still not , i have not yet updated , is it still there in update1

Comment: I also tested with XE... same behaviour... double-click = generate the vent and remove the action from the toolbar

Answer (score 2):

Don't double click on the button on your toolbar. Instead you should open your action manager and double click on the action that is assigned to the button in your toolbar that you wish to add code to it.

Comment: thanks ; this is what i am doing up to now ; but in some situations its very hard to control my self.